# Создание DatePickerTableCell в JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

**Доброго времени суток**
Хочу к таблице добавить DatePicker в ячейке чтоб пользователь мог выбрать дату.
Я знаю что необходимо наследовать элемент и создать свой компонент но у меня ничего из этого не получилось.
Был бы рад подробно описанному способу создания такого элемента.
*Заранее благодарен*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так будет выглядеть контроллер.

```
@FXML
private TableView<Pojo> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Pojo, String> c1;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Pojo, LocalDate> c2;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    c1.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().name));
    c2.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty(new DatePicker(param.getValue().localDate)));

    Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
    pojo.name = "Name";
    pojo.localDate = LocalDate.now();
    table.getItems().add(pojo);
}

private static class Pojo {
    String name;
    LocalDate localDate;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за  ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна CellFactory, которая при редактировании ячейки будет показывать DatePicker. Мой пример немного избыточен, т.к. поле у меня типа LocalDateTime, c LocalDate немного упростится.

```
    dateColumn = new TableColumn<>();
    dateColumn.setEditable(true);
    dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
    dateColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<T, LocalDateTime>, TableCell<T, LocalDateTime>>() {

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

        @Override
        public TableCell<T, LocalDateTime> call(TableColumn<T, LocalDateTime> param) {
            return new TableCell<T, LocalDateTime>() {

                private DatePicker datePicker;

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(LocalDateTime item, boolean empty) {
                    if (item == getItem())
                        return;

                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item == null) {
                        super.setText(null);
                        super.setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        super.setText(item.format(dtf));
                        super.setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void startEdit() {
                    if (!isEditable() || !getTableView().isEditable() || !getTableColumn().isEditable()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if(datePicker == null){
                        datePicker = createPicker();
                    }
                    datePicker.setValue(getItem().toLocalDate());

                    super.startEdit();
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(datePicker);
                }

                @Override
                public void cancelEdit() {
                    super.cancelEdit();

                    setText(getItem().format(dtf));
                    setGraphic(null);
                }

                private DatePicker createPicker() {
                    DatePicker picker = new DatePicker();
                    picker.setOnAction(event -> {
                        this.commitEdit(picker.getValue().atStartOfDay());
                        event.consume();
                    });
                    picker.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
                        if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                            this.cancelEdit();
                            event.consume();
                        }
                    });
                    return picker;
                }


            };
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

В восьмой джаве есть уже встроенный компонента [DatePicker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html).